# How do I compute this Fourier transform?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-transform

$$ f (t) = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{for } t < 0 \\ A_1 \exp( i \omega_1 t - \Gamma_1 t) & \quad \text{for } t \geq 0 \end{cases} $$

I need to Fourier-transform this using the formula

$$ g(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-iwt} dt $$

Subbing in the values and functions:

$$g(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty A_1 e^{iw_1t - r_1t} e^{-iwt} dt $$

I combined the exponential terms:

$$ g(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty e^{(i(w_1 -w)t - r_1 t)} dt $$

Factorising $t$ in the exponential term:

$$ g(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty e^{t(i(w_1 - w) - r_1)} $$

How do I carry on from here?

Comment: Use the fact that for any complex number $z\neq 0,$ the derivative of $t\mapsto e^{zt}$ is $ze^{zt}.$ This implies that a primitive of the same function is $\frac{e^{zt}}{z}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty e^{t(i(\omega_1 - \omega) -\Gamma_1 )}dt$$

$$g(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim\limits_{L \to \infty}\int_{0}^{L} e^{t(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}dt$$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim\limits_{L \to \infty}\int_{0}^{L} e^{t(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim\limits_{L \to \infty}\frac{1}{(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}e^{t(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}\bigg|_{0}^{L}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}\lim\limits_{L \to \infty}[e^{L(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}-1]$$

$$e^{L(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}=e^{-L\Gamma_1 }e^{iL(\omega_1 - \omega)}$$

We can notice that: $ 0\le |e^{iL(\omega_1 - \omega)} |\le1 $ then as $L\rightarrow  \infty$  we have that $e^{-L\Gamma_1 }e^{iL(\omega_1 - \omega)}\rightarrow 0$

Finally:

$$g(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{(i(\omega_1 - \omega) - \Gamma_1 )}(0-1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{(i(\omega-\omega_1 ) + \Gamma_1 )}$$

If we multiply by the complex conjugate from the denominator:

$$g(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\Gamma_1+i(\omega_1-\omega ) }{\omega ^2+\Gamma_1^2-\omega_1^{2}}$$